# Question on nCPA Security and Uniform Permutations

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, probabilistic-encryption

I feel I am misunderstanding the idea of nCPA security and its relation to uniform permutations. In particular I've been reading the paper "[Hoang, Morris Rogaway; An Enciphering Scheme Based on a Card Shuffle](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.1176)".

My understanding of the definition of nCPA security is the following.
Suppose that $E : \mathcal M \to \mathcal M$ is a permutation, ie $E(m) \neq E(m')$ for all $m \neq m'$.
Suppose also that $\pi$ is a permutation chosen uniformly at random.

The adversary $A$ is then given an oracle, which is either $E$ or $\pi$ -- but she does not know which; her aim is to find out which one it is. She is allowed to ask $q$ queries of her oracle, and then must make her decision as to which she thinks it is. (This is non-adaptive, in the sense that she must decide in advance which questions to ask.)

The nCPA advantage of $A$ is then defined as
$$ \bigl|
P(A \text{ says } E \mid E) - P(A \text{ says } E \mid \pi)
\bigr|.$$
(Note that this is the same as replacing "$\text{says } E$" by "$\text{says } \pi$", the probabilities sum to 1.)
This part I may not be understanding correctly.

For two distributions $\mu$ and $\nu$ on a space $\Omega$, the total variation distance is defined as
$$ \| \mu - \nu \|
=
\max_{A \subseteq \Omega} \bigl\| \mu(A) - \nu(A) \bigr\|. $$

In a related paper "[Morris, Rogaway, Stegers; How to Encipher Messages on a Small Domain](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/thorp.pdf)", the authors say

> Total variation distance is identical to the advantage with repsect to a (deterministic) nCPA (non-adaptive, chosen-plaintext attack).

I sort of see why this might be the case, but not exactly. (There is no proof given, just the statement.)

---

My main source of confusion, though, is the following.
In both the aforementioned papers, an enciphering scheme is given. Let's consider the first paper, for concreteness.
This requires random integers $K_1, ..., K_r$ from $\{1,...,N\}$ and random bits $\{b_{i,j} \mid i = 1,...,r, \, j = 1,...,N/2\}$. Here $r$ is order $\log N$.

One of the advantages, though, is that in order to encrypt some $m \in \mathcal M = \{1,...,N\}$, one only needs to know the keys $K_1, ..., K_r$ and $r$ of the bits. However, if one wishes to generate the whole permutation $E$, the entire key is required.

It seems to me that one could just draw a uniform permutation naively: draw $\pi_1 \sim U(\{1,...,N\})$, then $\pi_2 \sim U(\{1,...,n\}\setminus\{\pi_1\})$, and so on. This takes time order $N$ (by [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)); each round of the algorithm draws $N/2$ independent uniform bits, which I presume takes time order $N$. So if one wants the whole permutation, just draw it uniformly, rather than using an approximate method.

Alternatively, one wishes to just encrypt one, or a small number, of messages. Then just draw this part of the cipher. After all, one could just use the random integers $K_1, ..., K_r$. (Since $r \asymp \log n \ll \sqrt n$, with high probability all the $K_i$ will be different.)

---

Can someone explain to me what the *purpose* of a cipher, such as those described in the two linked papers, is?